# Python bindings for speech dispatcher fail on import (no module named speech)

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am attempting to use a program that has the Python API to speech dispatcher as a dependency. The code fails on the line that imports the speech dispatcher Python interface:

```
import speechd
```

I am on Ubuntu 20 LTS, and have the speech dispatcher package installed, as well as python3-speechd. When using the python3 REPL, `import speechd` fails with module not found.

How can I successfully get Python to recognize the bindings for speech dispatcher?

Comment: What is the result of this command? `python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9xMAvL3t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using Pyenv.

Versions of Python installed by Pyenv do not look for packages in the system directories (`/usr/lib/python3/...`), that's why installing `python3-speechd` does not work in your case.

So you have two choices:

1. Install `speechd` with your Pyenv version. There does not seem to be an easy way to install it, so you'd have to compile Speechd yourself first, then install the built Python package with `pip`.
2. Switch to the system Python version with `pyenv global system` (or `pyenv local system` if you want it only in the current directory). Then you should be able to `import speechd`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. pyenv was shadowing the system Python, which had access to the speech dispatcher bindings. When I switched to the system version of Python, the application worked.

Answer (score -1):

What tool are you using to code? (Jupyter notebook, PyCharm, etc.) I believe you need to pip install the package before you import it.

Please try one of the below:

```
!pip install speechd
```

```
pip install speechd
```

then you can run:

```
import speechd
```

Comment: I mean, yeah, I tried pip, and pip3, etc. 'speechd' isn't a valid pip module name, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32681837)